# Launch JXBrowser executable from User directory instead of temp folder

Tags: jxbrowser

I have hit a road block. We are using Jxbrowser and running into an issue where launching chromium process from temp folder is blocked on the machine. [image]

Is there any way to configure JXbrowser to launch it from user directory instead of temp folder ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sahil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JxBrowser extracts Chromium binaries into user's temp folder and run Chromium process from that directory. If you would like to change the folder for Chromium binaries, then use the `jxbrowser.chromium.dir` System Property that you need to initialize with path to the directory where the Chromium binaries should be located.

You can read more about this in the [Chromium Binaries](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000015146-chromium-binaries) article.

Comment: @VinitaVaswani What kind of files are still generated in the appData dir?